# "Model has not been defined" in sequelize with associations

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, nestjs

```
@Table
export class DepartmentModel extends Model{


     @AutoIncrement
    @Unique
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    id: number;

    @Column
    title: string;

    @Column
    headId: number;

    @Column
    @CreatedAt
    creationDate: Date;

    @Column
    departmentInfo: string;

    @HasMany(() => EmployeeModel, "id")
    employees: EmployeeModel[];}
```

```
@Table
export class EmployeeModel extends Model{

    @AutoIncrement
    @Unique
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    id: number;

    @Column
    firstName: string

    @Column
    surname: string

    @Column
    post: string

    @ForeignKey(() => DepartmentModel)
    @BelongsTo(() => DepartmentModel,'id')
    departmentId: DepartmentModel;
}
```

Department need to have an array of employees and every Employee need to have one department he belongs to.
And i have this error.

> EmployeeModel has not been defined

It looks almost like in documentation, what is the problem of this?

Comment: Looks a bit like circular references issue

Comment: Shouldn't `@ForeignKey(() => DepartmentModel)` be on `departmentId` instead of on `id`?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is still the same

Comment: ```@HasMany(() => EmployeeModel, "id") employees: EmployeeModel[];``` Problem is from here. But why? @Anatoly

Comment: Maybe this article https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de helps you

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you define the entity on  sequlize  object.

```
export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'SEQUELIZE',
    useFactory: async () => {
      const sequelize = new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: ------,
        username: '-----',
        password: '----',
        database: '----',
      });
      sequelize.addModels([EmployeeModel, OtherEntityHere]);
      await sequelize.sync( {alter: true});
      return sequelize;
    },
  },
];
```

or else sequlize wont know the entity and its telling you that its not defined too.